# Keras No module named models

Tags: python, keras

Try to run Keras in MacOSX, using a virtual environment

**Versions**

- MacOSX: 10.12.4 (16E195)
- Python 2.7

**Troubleshooting**

- Recreate Virtualenv
- Reinstall keras

**Logs**

```
(venv) me$sudo pip install --upgrade keras

Collecting keras
Requirement already up-to-date: six in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg (from keras)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyyaml in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from keras)
Requirement already up-to-date: theano in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from keras)
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.9.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from theano->keras)
Requirement already up-to-date: scipy>=0.14 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from theano->keras)
Installing collected packages: keras
Successfully installed keras-2.0.5

(venv) me$ python -c "import keras; print(keras.__version__)"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named keras
```

Comment: Do you have a module or package named `keras` in your folder? Rename it!

Comment: When I used "sudo" to install it was not accesible by python command, after removing sudo seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying problem here is what when you use `sudo`, `pip` points to the global, system-level python and not the virtual-env python. That is why, when you install without `sudo`, it works seamlessly for you. You can check this by running `sudo pip install --upgrade keras` from within the virtualenv and then running `python -c "import keras; print(keras.__version__)"` outside the virtualenv.